# ggplot2: How do I create a simple boxplot from a dataframe?

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I've been trying to do this boxplot now for a whole day. I give up soon. Please help. 
I just want a simple boxplot for my 3 groups, A, B and C. 
This is my data simplified:

```
> mydata 
   A01 A02 A03 B01 B02 B03 C01 C02 C03
id0001    1    2    3    6    7    8    11    12    13
```

A01, A02 and A03 should make up the confidence interval for A, etc. How can I have a very simple boxplot with the 3 groups on the x-axis?
Although boxes would be great too, I would be so grateful if someone could help me make my plot similar to [this one](http://compbio.mit.edu/cummeRbund/images/plots/cummeRbund-manual-gene_plots_line-4.png). Eventually, I want to make a graph that contains more than one ID, so it looks like [this one](http://compbio.mit.edu/cummeRbund/images/plots/cummeRbund-manual-similar_plots_2.png), but with error bars like the first one.

If someone could help me or give me tips on how to proceed, I would appreciate it so much!

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have enough data to draw a box plot. IIRC boxplots only make sense once you have more than 6 observations per group. The data you show has only 3 observations per group. Try a dotplot instead.

Comment: I do have more data, this was only an example of how an extract of the data look. I have about 6-7 values for each group. Anyway, I do believe it should be possible to plot the confidence intervals or error bars with only 3 data points. The images I linked to are based on 3 replicates for each line (gene), hence only 3 values per group.

Comment: You seem to be confusing confidence intervals/error bars with a box plot. A box plot is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) whereas a confidence interval is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval). Which do you want?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. You are probably right. I'm learning. Maybe box plots are wrong with this data. How can I view my data with error bars or confidence intervals like the images I linked? Have you any idea? I thought of them like box plots without the boxes. Probably they are something else then.

Comment: Do you think I should make a new question and remove the boxplot part?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you do want a boxplot (or any other plot from **ggplot2**) you'll need to coerce the data into the correct format. Here is an example based on similar data to that which you show:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:3, 6:8, 11:13), nrow = 1))
names(df) <- paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), 1:3)

sdf <- stack(df)

sdf <- transform(sdf, group = substring(ind, 1, 1),
                 obs = substring(ind, 2))
```

The data `sdf` are now in normalized format (or long format):

```
> head(sdf)
  values ind group obs
1      1  A1     A   1
2      2  A2     A   2
3      3  A3     A   3
4      6  B1     B   1
5      7  B2     B   2
6      8  B3     B   3
```

These data can then be easily plotted:

```
require(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(sdf, aes(x = group, y = values)) +
    geom_boxplot()
plt
```

producing:

[image]